# Qt How sent post HTTPS with SSL

Tags: c++, qt, ssl

Qt How send simple post HTTPS with SSL ?

The program is supposed to send posts via HTTPS using QNetworkAccessManager.

Below is a simple example of my code.

```
QUrlQuery params;
QByteArray dane;
params.addQueryItem("mWyslijpost", ui->lineEdit->text());
dane.append(params.toString());


QUrl url("https://81.2.244.83/Testpostssl/infotest.php");


QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request, dane);



QFile certFile(":/crt/cert.crt");
Q_ASSERT(certFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly));

QSslCertificate cert(&certFile, QSsl::Pem);

QSslSocket * sslSocket = new QSslSocket(this);
sslSocket->addCaCertificate(cert);

sslSocket->connectToHostEncrypted(SERVER,  443);

if (!sslSocket->waitForEncrypted())
{
    qDebug() << "Info " << sslSocket->errorString();
    return false;
}

QSslConfiguration config = sslSocket->sslConfiguration();
config.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2);

sslSocket->setSslConfiguration(config);
reply->setSslConfiguration(config);


// wait
QEventLoop elCzekaj;
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &elCzekaj, SLOT(quit()));
elCzekaj.exec();


if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
{
    qDebug() << reply->readAll();
 }
else
{
    qDebug() << "Error...";
    qDebug() << reply->errorString();
}
```

How to download certificates from server ?
How to configure QSsl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the cert from the peer try something like this:

```
QSslSocket *socket = new QSslSocket();

QObject::connect(socket,
                 &QSslSocket::encrypted,
                 [=](){qDebug() << socket->peerCertificate() << " cert";}
);

socket->connectToHostEncrypted("stackoverflow.com", 443);
```

Regarding the question: "How to configure QSsl", that depends on what you want to do. If you simply want to fetch something from a Webserver over TLS, just use the QNetworkAccessManager. The defaults there will do.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, you just need to use https in the address and QNetworkAccessManager will handle it.